# How to fix RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration in Python

Tags: python, deque, algorithmic-trading, lob

I'm trying to implement market simulation for algorithmic trading and I've found this code on github https://github.com/DrAshBooth/PyLOB.
The problem is when I'm running my code for small window, for example, 2 days, everything is fine and I get my expected results. But when I increase window to 20 days or more, I get "RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration".
I've checked my code but I've never found anything that could mutate deque during my runs.
Below is the part of the code that produces the error:

```
    self.tape = deque(maxlen=None)
    .
    .
    .
    def avg_volume_traded(self):
       if self.tape != None and len(self.tape) > 0:
          num = 0
          total_volume = 0
          for entry in self.tape:
             total_volume = entry['qty'] + total_volume
             num += 1
          if num != 0 and total_volume != None:
             return total_volume, num
       else:
          return None, None
```

This is the actual error message:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-10986:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hamid/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/home/hamid/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "exchange_envirnment.py", line 60, in _doit
        self.func(self.args[0], self.args[1])
      File "/home/hamid/dukto/src2/src_new/traders/market_maker_trader.py", line 46, in trade
        self.type_three(lob_obj, reporter_obj)
      File "/home/hamid/dukto/src2/src_new/traders/market_maker_trader.py", line 285, in type_three
        max_volume = lob_obj.max_volume_traded()
      File "/home/hamid/dukto/src2/src_new/PyLOB/orderbook.py", line 395, in max_volume_traded
        for entry in self.tape:
    RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration
```

This is the main part that use threading in two parts(class Periodic and day_period):

```
class Periodic(object):
    def __init__(self, object, compression_factor, args=[], kwargs={}):
        self.compression_factor = compression_factor
        self.object = object
        self.func = object.trade
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.seppuku = Event()
    def start(self):
        self.seppuku.clear()
        self.proc = Thread(target=self._doit)
        self.proc.start()
    def stop(self):
        self.seppuku.set()
        self.proc.join()
    def _doit(self):
        while True:
            self.seppuku.wait(self.object.interval / self.compression_factor)
            if self.seppuku.is_set():
                break
            self.func(self.args[0], self.args[1])

class day_period(object):
    def __init__(self, object, compression_factor, args=[], kwargs={}):
        self.period = (3600 * 4) / compression_factor
        self.func = object.run
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.seppuku = Event()
    def start(self):
        self.seppuku.clear()
        self.proc = Thread(target=self._doit)
        self.proc.start()
    def stop(self):
        self.seppuku.set()
        self.proc.join()
    def _doit(self):
        while True:
            self.seppuku.wait(self.period)
            if self.seppuku.is_set():
                break
            self.func(self.args)

class intra_day_traders_mng(object):
    def __init__(self, simulation_config):
        self.config = simulation_config
        self.agents_list = []
        self.agents_dict = {}
        self.p_list = []
        self.compression_factor = simulation_config['simulation_config']['compression_factor']
        self.trader_creator()
        self.first_time = True
        self.day_of_simulation  = simulation_config['simulation_config']['day_number']

    def trader_creator(self):
        for agent_name in self.config['agents']['intra_day']:
            for config in self.config['agents']['intra_day'][agent_name]:
                if agent_name == 'nonclassified_trader':
                    for k in range(config['n_traders']):
                        self.agents_list.append(NON_CLASSIFIED_TRADER_INTRADAY(config))
                        time.sleep(.1)
        for agent_name in self.config['agents']['daily']:
            for config in self.config['agents']['daily'][agent_name]:
                if agent_name == 'nonclassified_trader':
                    for k in range(config['n_traders']):
                        self.agents_list.append(NON_CLASSIFIED_TRADER_DAILY(config))
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                if agent_name == "market_maker_trader":
                    for k in range(config['n_traders']):
                        self.agents_list.append(MARKET_MAKER_TRADER_DAILY(config))
                        time.sleep(0.1)
        for agent in self.agents_list:
            self.agents_dict.update({agent.id: agent})
        for agent in self.agents_list:
            agent.set_trader_dict(self.agents_dict)

    def random_initial(self):
        agents_random_list = random.choices(self.agents_list, k=len(self.agents_list))
        return agents_random_list

    def run(self, args):
        lob = args[0]
        reporter_obj = args[1]
        # when the trader running for first time
        if self.first_time == True:
            lob.time_obj.reset()
            agents_random_list = self.random_initial()
            for agent in agents_random_list:
                self.p_list.append(Periodic(agent, self.compression_factor, args=(lob,reporter_obj)))
                self.p_list[-1].start()
                time.sleep(.1)
            self.first_time = False
        else:
            for proc in self.p_list:
                proc.stop()
            for agent in self.agents_list:
                agent.reset_trader(lob)
            time_series = lob.ohcl()
            if len(time_series) == self.day_of_simulation :
                out = {'out':time_series}
                with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(out, outfile)
                reporter_obj.save_as_csv()
                trade_summary = lob.trade_summary()
                with open('trade_report.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
                    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                    writer.writerows(trade_summary)
                csvFile.close()
                sys.exit()
            print("***********************************************************************************")
            print("day is:",lob.time_obj.day)
            lob.time_obj.reset()
            for proc in self.p_list:
                proc.start()
                time.sleep(.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
        simulation_config = json.load(f)
    intra_day_mng_obj = intra_day_traders_mng(simulation_config)
    reporter_obj = REPORTER()
    # for synchronization of time
    time_obj = TIME_MANAGE(compression_factor=simulation_config['simulation_config']['compression_factor'])
    lob = OrderBook(time_obj, tick_size=simulation_config['simulation_config']['tickSize'])
    day_period(intra_day_mng_obj, simulation_config['simulation_config']['compression_factor'], args=(lob,reporter_obj)).start()
```

And finally the "OrderBook" that defines "self.tape" in the below code:

```
class OrderBook():
    def __init__(self, time_obj, tick_size=0.0001):
        self.tape = deque(maxlen=None)  # Index [0] is most recent trade
        self.bids = OrderTree()
        self.asks = OrderTree()
        self.lastTick = None
        self.lastTimestamp = 0
        self.tickSize = tick_size
        self.time = 0
        self.nextQuoteID = 0
        self.time_series = []
        self.time_obj = time_obj

    def clipPrice(self, price):
        return round(price, int(math.log10(1 / self.tickSize)))

    def updateTime(self):
        self.time = int(self.time_obj.now()['time'])

    def processOrder(self, quote, fromData, verbose):
        orderType = quote['type']
        orderInBook = None
        if fromData:
            self.time = quote['timestamp']
        else:
            self.updateTime()
            quote['timestamp'] = self.time
        if quote['qty'] <= 0:
            sys.exit('processLimitOrder() given order of qty <= 0')
        if not fromData: self.nextQuoteID += 1
        if orderType == 'market':
            trades = self.processMarketOrder(quote, verbose)
        elif orderType == 'limit':
            quote['price'] = self.clipPrice(quote['price'])
            trades, orderInBook = self.processLimitOrder(quote, fromData, verbose)
        else:
            sys.exit("processOrder() given neither 'market' nor 'limit'")
        return trades, orderInBook

    def processOrderList(self, side, orderlist,
                         qtyStillToTrade, quote, verbose):
        trades = []
        qtyToTrade = qtyStillToTrade
        while len(orderlist) > 0 and qtyToTrade > 0:
            headOrder = orderlist.getHeadOrder()
            tradedPrice = headOrder.price
            counterparty = headOrder.tid
            if qtyToTrade < headOrder.qty:
                tradedQty = qtyToTrade
                newBookQty = headOrder.qty - qtyToTrade
                headOrder.updateQty(newBookQty, headOrder.timestamp)
                qtyToTrade = 0
            elif qtyToTrade == headOrder.qty:
                tradedQty = qtyToTrade
                if side == 'bid':
                    self.bids.removeOrderById(headOrder.idNum)
                else:
                    self.asks.removeOrderById(headOrder.idNum)
                qtyToTrade = 0
            else:
                tradedQty = headOrder.qty
                if side == 'bid':
                    self.bids.removeOrderById(headOrder.idNum)
                else:
                    self.asks.removeOrderById(headOrder.idNum)
                qtyToTrade -= tradedQty
            if verbose: print('>>> TRADE \nt=%d $%f n=%d p1=%d p2=%d' %
                              (self.time, tradedPrice, tradedQty,
                               counterparty, quote['tid']))

            transactionRecord = {'timestamp': self.time,
                                 'price': tradedPrice,
                                 'qty': tradedQty,
                                 'time': self.time,
                                 'day': self.time_obj.now()['day']}
            if side == 'bid':
                transactionRecord['party1'] = [counterparty,
                                               'bid',
                                               headOrder.idNum]
                transactionRecord['party2'] = [quote['tid'],
                                               'ask',
                                               None]
            else:
                transactionRecord['party1'] = [counterparty,
                                               'ask',
                                               headOrder.idNum]
                transactionRecord['party2'] = [quote['tid'],
                                               'bid',
                                               None]
            self.tape.append(transactionRecord)
            trades.append(transactionRecord)
        return qtyToTrade, trades

    def processMarketOrder(self, quote, verbose):
        trades = []
        qtyToTrade = quote['qty']
        side = quote['side']
        if side == 'bid':
            while qtyToTrade > 0 and self.asks:
                bestPriceAsks = self.asks.minPriceList()
                qtyToTrade, newTrades = self.processOrderList('ask',
                                                              bestPriceAsks,
                                                              qtyToTrade,
                                                              quote, verbose)
                trades += newTrades
        elif side == 'ask':
            while qtyToTrade > 0 and self.bids:
                bestPriceBids = self.bids.maxPriceList()
                qtyToTrade, newTrades = self.processOrderList('bid',
                                                              bestPriceBids,
                                                              qtyToTrade,
                                                              quote, verbose)
                trades += newTrades
        else:
            sys.exit('processMarketOrder() received neither "bid" nor "ask"')
        return trades

    def processLimitOrder(self, quote, fromData, verbose):
        orderInBook = None
        trades = []
        qtyToTrade = quote['qty']
        side = quote['side']
        price = quote['price']
        if side == 'bid':
            while (self.asks and
                   price >= self.asks.minPrice() and
                   qtyToTrade > 0):
                bestPriceAsks = self.asks.minPriceList()
                qtyToTrade, newTrades = self.processOrderList('ask',
                                                              bestPriceAsks,
                                                              qtyToTrade,
                                                              quote, verbose)

                trades += newTrades
            if qtyToTrade > 0:
                if not fromData:
                    quote['idNum'] = self.nextQuoteID
                quote['qty'] = qtyToTrade
                self.bids.insertOrder(quote)
                orderInBook = quote
        elif side == 'ask':
            while (self.bids and
                   price <= self.bids.maxPrice() and
                   qtyToTrade > 0):
                bestPriceBids = self.bids.maxPriceList()
                qtyToTrade, newTrades = self.processOrderList('bid',
                                                              bestPriceBids,
                                                              qtyToTrade,
                                                              quote, verbose)
                trades += newTrades
            if qtyToTrade > 0:
                if not fromData:
                    quote['idNum'] = self.nextQuoteID
                quote['qty'] = qtyToTrade
                self.asks.insertOrder(quote)
                orderInBook = quote
        else:
            sys.exit('processLimitOrder() given neither bid nor ask')
        return trades, orderInBook

    def avg_volume_traded(self):
        if self.tape != None and len(self.tape) > 0:
            num = 0
            total_volume = 0
            for entry in self.tape:
                total_volume = entry['qty'] + total_volume
                num += 1
            if num != 0 and total_volume != None:
                return total_volume, num
        else:
            return None, None
```

Comment: Can you show us the other code that uses `self.tape`? The fact that the error traceback is rooted in python's threading module suggests that you do in fact have another thread modifying the deque...

Comment: Thanks @Tom Dalton.I have added codes. Any suggestion?

Comment: You've added a lot of code, but none of it uses `self.tape` nor appears to be the class that defines `self.tape`. So I can't suggest anything. The code that will be useful to find the issue is all the code related to the class defining self.tape, and the code relating to launching/running stuff in threads.

Comment: I have added the "OrderBook" that defines "self.tape". About the last part of your comment, I've attached 4 python scripts which the third one contains "class periodic" and "class day_period" use threading. Have I got your point?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to competing accesses between *processOrderList()* and *avg_volume_traded()*.  The former modifies the deque while the latter is iterating over the deque.

An easy solution is to have *list()* atomically extract the data from the deque in *avg_volume_traded()*:

```
def avg_volume_traded(self):
   if self.tape != None and len(self.tape) > 0:
      num = 0
      total_volume = 0
      for entry in list(self.tape):     # <-- atomic extraction step
         total_volume = entry['qty'] + total_volume
         num += 1
      if num != 0 and total_volume != None:
         return total_volume, num
   else:
      return None, None
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using threads. And it is very likely that self.tape is changed by another thread. You should try and block that thread from mutating self.tape during execution of avg_volume_traded.

Answer (score 1):

As **Tom Dalton** noted, this exception can be thrown due to self.tape modification in different thread. I encountered this problem before, as for me, I fixed it by creating a Lock.
I can also suggest you just to ignore this exception, but this can lead to an undefiend behaviour

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use Lock? I really don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Yes, sure. Lock() object is low level synchronization mechanism in python that allow you synchronize threads. You can read more about it here https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Comment: I added the scripts of the main file that in two classes - Periodic and day_period- we call threading. As I am not good in programming can you add the lock in the proper place?

Comment: What's confusing about this is that the system docs for deque state "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction." IMO, throw a runtime error isn't "thread safe". It's just a different level of "not thread safe"